# Show that the set $A$ is not an open nor a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to show that the set $A=\left \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}, n>0\right \}$ is not an open nor a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show also that the set $B=A\cup \{0\}$ is not open but closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

The set $A$ is not open, since $0$ is a limit but it is not included in the set.

The set $A$ is not closed: For each $\epsilon >0$ there is a $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n}$. So for each $\epsilon>0$ the intersection $(0-\epsilon, 0+\epsilon)\cap A$ is non-empty. How do we continue?

If we consider my justification that $A$ is not open shouldn't $B$ be open?

Comment: A set is **closed** if it contains all its limit points. This is not the criterion for open sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is closed $iff$ it contains all its limit points. $0$ is a limit point, not in $A$, therefore $A$ is not closed.
$A$ is not open since, if you take $1 \in A$, then you can't fit a ball of any radius $r$ inside $A$, ie the interval $(1-r,1+r)$ is not in $A$.

$B$ is not open for the same reasons as $A$. $B$ contains all its limit points, so it's closed.

Comment: Why is the interval $(1-r, 1+r)$ not in $A$ ? As for $B$, we know that the limit point $0$ is included, but how do we know that **all** limit points are included?

Comment: The elements of $A$ are 1, 1/2,1/3,..... choose $r<1/2$, and check whether the interval $(1-r,1+r)$ is in A (it is not). 0 is the only limit point.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only limit point of $A$ is $0$.

Without its limit point $A$ is not closed and with it, it is closed.

$A$ is not open because its complement is not closed.

Its complement is union of disjoint open intervals which do not include their boundary points.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)